# How to have different images at different sections of a single TableViewcell, having collection view placed inside a tableviewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[I want different images under different heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svz6b.png)

```
//ViewController.swift
  var categories = ["Good Afternoon","Daily Mixes","Bollywood Gems","Daily Mixes","Bollywood Gems","Bollywood Romantic","Pop","Trending Now","Top Charts","Saavn Originals","New Releases","Top Playlists","Radio Stations","Editorial Picks" ]

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return categories[section]
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRowTableViewCell
        return cell
}


// custom.swift

@IBOutlet weak var pic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

func execute() 
{
print("This is working")
pic.layer.cornerRadius = pic.frame.size.width/2
pic.clipsToBounds = true
    print("working")

}


// CategoryRowTableViewCell.swift

let main : [String] = ["black forest","butterscotch","Truffle","a","b","c","d","e","j","k","u","q","s","z"]


@IBOutlet weak var collect: UICollectionView!





func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 14
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collect.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videocell", for: indexPath) as! custom
     cell.execute()
     cell.pic.image = UIImage(named : main[indexPath.row])
     cell.text.text = main[indexPath.row]
     print(cell.text.text!)

    return cell

}
```

I am having a table view in that I am having an table view cell.
I am having different sections of table view cell .
In That cell a scroll view, on it collection view and collection view cell.
My Collection view cell contain a image and a label
I want to display different images in different row in collection view cell. But I am getting same images in every section of table view cell.Please help me in this.

Comment: Without code, it's hard to tell. Did you reload the collectionView inside the UITableViewCell? Is it a reuse issue?

Comment: Do if you can show your code

Comment: You'd probably need to handle datsource in a better way

Comment: I have uploaded the code . Now Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView meaning you do not need to have a UICollectionView in a Scroll view if I am understanding your structure correctly. The collection view will scroll once the images/content exceed the views frame. UITableViews also inherit from UIScrollView so it will also already have the functionality to scroll once content size exceeds the table view's frame.

Having a collection view in every table view cell might not be the best way to achieve what you need/want. However the issue seems to be that you are assigning the same data source to each collection view, but without seeing any code I will have to guess that you are creating a collection view assigning it the data and then adding it to each table view cell.

Comment: I have uploaded the code . Please can you resolve this now.

Comment: Okay with the way you have structured it it will be a bit difficult to separate what images go where. So to fix this you will need to pass the images into each table view cell separately. So make the "main" array public and instead of defining what is in it within the table view cell class, pass in the image names for each section in the cellForRowAt delegate method in the viewController.

Comment: Your view controller will have to have multiple arrays, or an array of array which will allow you to access specific arrays per index path provided in the cellForRowAt delegate method

Comment: If you need I can provide an example of this?

Comment: That would be great and easy to understand , please provide me one.